# How to generate sequence of numbers for every task in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using below code for mapping some data in spark. I need a unique sequential number to be generated for every task while mapping it to pair rdd. I tried using  the accumulators. But I got to know from the exceptions that retrieving the value form an accumulator is not possible inside the task. Please help me on this as I am very new to spark and have no idea about the solution.

```
Accumulator<Integer> uniqueIdAccumulator = context.getJavaSparkContext().accumulator(0, "uniqueId");
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd1 = javaPairRdd.mapToPair(f-> {
    uniqueIdAccumulator.add(1);
    return new Tuple2<String,String>(f._1, this.getMessageString(f._2, null,uniqueIdAccumulator.value()));
});
```

Comment: That looks like you're mapping a unique ID to each pair, not to each task (a task is usually defined as a partition of the RDD).

Comment: @RealSkeptic does that mean we can not assign accumulators to pairs? If not what will be the best way to achieve the required functionality. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. I just wondered if you really wanted a unique ID per task (which you can do with `mapPartitionWithIndex`) or a unique ID per pair (for which you should look into `zipWithUniqueID` or `zipWithIndex`).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I believe `zipWithUniqueID` will not be continuous. Also I need to use the id inside the pair rdd tasks. So How can I access that? Can you please share some code snippets on that?

Comment: so use `zipWithIndex`. And then in the **next** stage you use the extra data to calculate your function.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaPairRDD rdd1 = javaPairRdd.zipWithIndex().mapToPair(f-> { 
         return new Tuple2(f._1._1,this.getMessageString(f._1._2, null, f._2));
            });`

There is no need of accumulator here. ZipWithIndex helped getting the solution. ZipWIthIndex returns a RDD with the existing tuple and Long index number. I used the index number to generate the unique sequence number.